# Box-shadow CSS style not working in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I am using this to set the box-shadow property for a couple of images on my page and it works great on Firefox and Chrome, but refuses to work on Internet Explorer 9.

```
box-shadow: 0px0.5px8px1px  #888888;
```

AND

```
box-shadow: rgb(150,150,150) 0 0 20px;
```

Should I be using somthing else inorder for it be compaitble with IE9?

Comment: `box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 8px 1px #888888;` works fine for me in IE9. Your IE9 using a different browser mode? Different document mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me in IE9:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(28, 24, 28, 0.65);
```

same with hex:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000;
```

If this don't help, try this:
Press F12 and read what browsermod/documentmode you use. Than we can help you more.

Comment: The Browser mode:IE9 DocumentMode:IE9 Standards. Do I need to change it?

Comment: I have the exact same syntax but no it doesnt seem to work! It continues to work on Firefox and chrome though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sparky672 and ShogunArts.de for their posts. 
The css posted by them is supported by IE9.

The problem I had was that my custom branding forced IE8 mode on the page. Once I changed this to IE9 in the meta tag all the styles showed up just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I also had a custom branding that was set to IE8 browser mode.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Once I changed it to IE9 it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth checking that IE9 isn't in IE7 mode. Check your IE Developer tools. IE9 needs to be in IE9 mode for `box-shadow` to work.

Answer (score 0):

worked perfectly for me in this way without the htc file

```
.shadow{
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    border:1px solid #bebebe;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #CCC;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5)";
    opacity:1;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The order doesn't matter (color first -> values or vice versa) just make sure that the numeric values are in order.

Make sure to include spaces between your values. Also using just 0 is invalid (it should be 0px).

If you need more help, take a look at this:
http://yearofmoo.com/2011/03/ie9-and-css3-box-shadow/

Comment: **Quote:**  _"using just 0 is invalid"_.  Wrong.  Units are _optional_ when the value is zero.  See section 5... http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/

Comment: Do you have a reference for `0` alone being invalid (i.e. without a measurement)? I always thought that it wasn't necessary to pass in a unit, because 0px = 0em = 0cm, etc.

Comment: You are correct, @BenM.  [Here is the W3C spec for `box-shadow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow) where `0` alone (without units) is even used within their examples.

Comment: After putting this in the W3C validator:

body { box-shadow:0 0 5px #ddd; }

I end up with the following error:

0 is not a box-shadow value : 0 0 5px #ddd ... try it out for yourself http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator